# mongodb Can't get the query to work

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do a query in mongodb but I can't get it to work.

My document looks something like this.

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5305e54133e65b7341d63af3"),
    "clients" : [ 
        {
            "aggregations" : {
                "department" : [ 
                    "department1", 
                    "department3"
                ],
                "customer" : "customer2"
            },
            "lastLogin" : ISODate("2014-02-26T09:41:56.445Z"),
            "locale" : "en"
            "name" : "Test",
            "validFrom" : null,
            "validTo" : null,
            "visiting" : {
                "phone" : "031-303030",
                "company" : "MyCompany",
                "office" : [ 
                    "jag är ett test", 
                     "lite mer data"
                ],
                "country" : "Norge"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "approvedEmailSent" : true,
            "lastLogin" : ISODate("2014-03-01T15:27:12.252Z"),
            "locale" : "en",
            "name" : "Test2",
            "visiting" : {
                "phone" : "031-307450",
                "company" : "Other Company",
                "branch" : "Advertising agency"
            }
        }
    ],
    "firstname" : "Greger",
    "lastname" : "Aronsson",
    "username" : "TheUsername"
}
```

As you can see a user can have many clients. They are matched by name. The clients have visiting.company but sometimes this will not be the case.

I want to query where the clients.name is Test and regexp for visting.company and also firstname, lastname. If I'm logged in at Test2 I don't want hits on visiting.company "MyCompany". Hope this makes sense!

Comment: ok, so what have you tried?

Comment: db.users.find({  $and : [ {"clients" : {$elemMatch : { "name" : "Test" , $or :[ {"visiting.company" : /gre/i} ] }}} , {$or :[{"firstname" : /gre/i}]}] });

client.name = Test
firstname = "Greger"
visiting.company = "Test"

I want clients.name to be exact match but if firstname or visiting is found I want a hit.

Answer (score 0):

You can write query like :

```
db.visitCompany2.find({ $or : [
    {'clients.name': 'Test2'},       //Company name
    {'clients.visiting.company': {
        $regex: /Other/g          //Your visiting company regex
    }},
    {firstname: "Greger"},
    {"lastname": "Aronsson}"
]}, {
    'clients.$': 1,             //projection for clients
    firstname: 1,
    lastname: 1
});
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5305e54133e65b7341d63af3"),
    "clients": [{
        "approvedEmailSent": true,
        "lastLogin": ISODate("2014-03-01T15:27:12.252Z"),
        "locale": "en",
        "name": "Test2",
        "visiting": {
            "phone": "031-307450",
            "company": "Other Company",
            "branch": "Advertising agency"
        }
    }],
    "firstname": "Greger",
    "lastname": "Aronsson"
}
```

Comment: I must like search firstname, lastname and clients.visiting.company and I don't know i clients.visiting.company even exists.

Comment: in case if clients.visiting.company doesn't exist what you want ?

Comment: Will you please elaborate this line' If I'm logged in at Test2 I don't want hits on visiting.company "MyCompany" '?

Comment: A User have an array of clients. I want to be able to find the user by a search that has firstname like the search or lastname like the search or clients.visiting.company like the search but only in the array where clients.name is a predefined value. If The search matches any firstname, lastname or clients.visiting.company then I want to present the user but only for clients.name [Test].

Comment: you can do $or in your condition  { $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }

Comment: I think this is ok. Now I want to search for visiting.company within that client.

db.users.find({  $and : [ {"clients" : {$elemMatch : { "name" : "Test"  }}} , {$or :[{"firstname" : /gre/i},{"lastname" : /gre/i}, {"email" : /gre/i}]}] });

Comment: No I can't do or because if visiting.company doesn't exists then I get no hit or if visiting.company does not hit but firstname does it still doesn't give me a hit.